# restsharp postman code multipart post request sending 0kb images to JIRA

Tags: c#, rest, postman, restsharp, jira-rest-api

i am working on posting images to a JIRA ticket via their rest API( requires a multipart post with custom headers) . 
Everything works when in postman , the restsharp code that it generates is as follows :

```
var client = new RestClient("jira link here");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "31321");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "atlassian.xsrf.token=BMR0-T49H-M7PK-ZG4J_4f2a8b5df5dfd91780d88b5ea26f8de0_lin; JSESSIONID=CE20BD6E7D3FABA7A0E8F9403907CD97");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader("Host", "classified");
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "b5f2a773-532a-47b7-83bd-36c3cce16b55,d07661e4-abf5-408e-be59-0360938b6b77");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.18.0");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "classified");
request.AddHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"1280px-Microsoft_Azure_Logo.svg - Copy.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

i suspected the issue could be not having the full path of the image , tried adding the path , now it is posting the image , but the image is blank , 0kb. the image name is correct when posted to JIRA.

the image seems to be right , but is blank with the right name .

i also tried including request.addFile("x",@path);
still doesn't work .

This is the response from the server :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWijt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out , postman adds a bunch of extra stuff to its auto generated code , anyways the code generation on postman needs to be fixed , here's how i fixed mine :

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("link here");
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/attachments");
            restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Length", int.MaxValue.ToString());
            restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "secret");
            restRequest.AddHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");

            restRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            restRequest.AddFile("file", path);

            var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```